# R - ggplot2 change x-axis values to non-log values

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am plotting some payment distribution information and I aggregated the data after scaling it to log-normal (base-e). The histograms turn out great but I want to modify the x-axis to display the non-log equivalents.

My current axis displays [0:2.5:10] values
Alternatively, I would like to see values for exp(2.5), exp(5), etc.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Anything I can add to my plotting statement to scale the x-axis values? Maybe there's a better approach - thoughts?

Current code:

```
ggplot(plotData, aes_string(pay, fill = pt)) + geom_histogram(bins = 50) + facet_wrap(~M_P)
```

[image]

Answered...Final plot:
[image]

Comment: Is this solved if you exponentiate the data and then log-scale the x-axis?

Comment: @josliber applying "+scale_x_log10()" is limiting. What if you want scale using a distribution using a different log base?

Comment: @NikolayRodionov If you look at the documentation of `scale_x_log10` you'll see that it is just a convenience function with a specific `trans` argument to `scale_x_continuous`. You can use whatever transformation you'd like - logarithm of any base, or anything else.

Comment: @Gregor your right, thanks. Still running into the same issue though -- if I use scale_x_log10() the x axis values are still 1 to 10. Any way to change the x values to the 10^x equivalents? My goal is to keep the original axis value labels while maintaining the log grouping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are after but you can change the text of the x axis labels to whatever you want using scale_x_continuous.

Here's without:

```
ggplot(data = cars) + geom_histogram(aes(x = speed), binwidth = 1)
```

Here's with:

```
ggplot(data = cars) + geom_histogram(aes(x = speed), binwidth = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(5,10,15,20,25), labels=c(exp(5), exp(10), exp(15), exp(20), exp(25)))
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked out great!