# ggplot2 geom_smooth with variable as factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I have a small issue, which I can ridiculously not solve myself.

I have a simple data frame, which I want to plot with `ggplot2`. When I use the variable **weight** as a factor I get all values in the x-axis, s. *plot 2*, but not when I use it as integer, s. *plot 1*. However, I want to use `geom_smooth`, which seems to function only with *plot 1*, but not in *plot 2* where **weight** is a factor.

How do I get a graph in `ggplot2`, which shows me all values of **weight** and additionally the `geom_smooth` function?

Consider [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/example.csv) example file:

```
require(ggplot2)

x <- get.url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/example.csv)
app_df <- read.csv(x, header=T, sep = ",", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "..")     
colnames(app_df) <- c("Date", "Weight")

date <- as.Date(strptime(app_df$Date, "%d.%m.%Y"))
weight <- app_df$Weight
df <- na.omit(data.frame(date,weight))

# plot 1 (only few values indicated in x axis)
ggplot(df, aes(date,weight)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = "1")) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

# plot 2 (no smooth function)
ggplot(df, aes(date,as.factor(weight))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = "1")) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem. In the plot 1 you get 16 data points and trend line (`geom_smooth`). Also in  the plot 2 you get 16 points but this plot is wrong because weight has to be used as integer and not the factor.

Comment: Factor variables are essentially categorical variables. You can't fit a linear or whatever function to them. As for the integer values not all showing up, you can use `scale_y_continuous` to customize limits and breaks.

Comment: Hi, Gopala, how would you use `scale_y_continous` in the present example so that I get the same 16 data points in the x axis as in plot 2?

Comment: I can see no plots in your question, and your link is broken. Maybe you could update the question, so that the rest of community can also learn from it?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
require(ggplot2)

x <- url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109495328/example.csv")
app_df <- read.csv(x, header=T, sep = ",", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "..")     
colnames(app_df) <- c("Date", "Weight")

date <- as.Date(strptime(app_df$Date, "%d.%m.%Y"))
weight <- app_df$Weight
df <- na.omit(data.frame(date,weight))

# plot 1 (only few values indicated in x axis)
ggplot(df, aes(date,weight)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = "1")) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")

# plot 2 (no smooth function)
ggplot(df, aes(date,as.numeric(as.factor(weight)))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = "1")) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Comment: Richo64, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not what I wanted. I want to have combination of plot 1 and 2, where I have the trend line with all 16 data points indicated at the x axis as in plot 2.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262341/r-ggplot2-change-x-axis-values-to-non-log-values/35263049#35263049) help?